# what did i do wrong missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: python, class, self

```py
class Area(object):
    def __init__(self, base, height):
        self.base = base
        self.height = height

    def calculation(self):
        return(self.base * self.height)

area = Area(15, 2)
print(Area.calculation())
```

Comment: Change your last line to 
print(Area.calculation(area))

Answer (score 0):

The `Area` in your `print()` is capitalized, while your variable `area` is not. That means that you are calling the Area Object instead of the variable.
This should work :

```
class Area(object):
    def __init__(self, base, height):
        self.base = base
        self.height = height

    def calculation(self):
        return(self.base * self.height)

area = Area(15, 2)
print(area.calculation())
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the class object's `calculation` method (`Area.calculation`), instead of calling the `calculation` method of the `Area` *instance* (`area.calculation`). This works:

```py
class Area(object):
    def __init__(self, base, height):
        self.base = base
        self.height = height

    def calculation(self):
        return self.base * self.height

area = Area(15, 2)
print(area.calculation())
```

Note the removed parentheses around the `return` argument - they are unnecessary as `return` is a keyword, not a function.